# What is The Best Way to Make Parallax header effect for wordpress theme ?? pure CSS or using JavaScript?

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, javascript, browser-compatibility

I'm new in wordpress theme development, I want ask some question here,
I want to make a parallax effect for my theme header like this:

[TestParallax.com](http://test.bos.la/)

this is made by using some JS code, I want to know what is the best way for WP Theme ?? using pure CSS or using JS ??  what is the most compatible for web browser ?? please help me guys ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Parallax effect for header using pure CSS as well as jQuery. The difference between them is the loading time. CSS will load much faster than jQuery. Implementing a feature will depend on the developer/owner of the theme how they want the feature to be. My preference is that you use pure CSS rather than jQuery.

Below are the two examples one with pure CSS and other with jQuery combination:

1. [Pure CSS](http://www.cssscript.com/twitter-like-header-parallax-effect-using-pure-css-css3/)
2. [jQuery](http://1stwebdesigner.com/parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: thank's, I'm prefer for CSS to, it's more simple, thank's for this link: [Pure CSS](http://www.cssscript.com/twitter-like-header-parallax-effect-using-pure-css-css3/) that's very helpfull

Comment: but I'm corius, why if we use jQuery that is more slow than CSS ???

Comment: jQuery will load slower because whenever we create a custom theme from scratch we need to follow some rules [Blocking JS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and [Google page speed rules](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules). As per the rule,you JS should be called after loading whole page content